# Python 3.x: Find if substring is at the end of a string w/o using endswith()

Tags: python, string

I have created a program to check if a string is a substring of another string, with the added condition of that substring being at the end.

```
def atEnd(first, second):
    if second in first and first.endswith(second):
        return True
    else:
        return False
first, second = input('Enter two strings: ').split()
print(atEnd(first, second))
```

Is there a way to find the same outcome without using the .endswith() function?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `endswith`? It's a perfectly cromulent method.

Comment: Why do you have `second in first`, `first.endswith(second)` covers both conditions.

Comment: Your question sound to me like "How to steer a car without using the steering wheel?". If you don't want to use the most obvious and convenient solution to the problem, then please explain your decision.

Answer (score 3):

```
first[-len(second):] == second
```

Will do the job.

Comment: Well, the question eliminates the obvious readable method. What makes this particularly inefficient?

Comment: Your slice operation means you'll end up copying the string needlessly. I expect this would be significantly slower than `endswith` if you benchmarked it.

Comment: Sure, I agree - of course in any practical setting it would be better to use the built-in method.

Comment: @DanielPryden if memory is a concern then something like: `second and all(a == b for a, b in zip(reversed(first), reversed(second)))` - but unless you're going to be dealing with large lengths of `second` - it's more overhead than worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `atEnd` function is completely redundant with `str.endswith`, which is a built-in native method and therefore will already have a highly efficient implementation.

I would simply write `print(first.endswith(second))` -- there's no need to complicate things further.

If you really want a free function rather than a method for some reason, then you can just invoke `str.endswith` directly: `print(str.endswith(first, second))`.

If you want to write your own implementation for efficiency reasons, you'll probably be better off using an alternative algorithm (e.g. building a suffix tree). If you want to write your own implementation to understand low-level string operations you really should learn C and read [the CPython implementation source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13450). If you are doing this because a school assignment told you not to use `endswith` then that seems like a dumb assignment to me -- you should probably ask your teacher for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `re` module's method `findall`:

```
import re   

EndsWith = lambda first,second: re.findall("("+first+")$",second) != []
```